# How to obtain the symmetric difference between two DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the `Spark` 1.6 API (Scala) `Dataframe` has functions for intersect and except, but not one for difference. Obviously, a combination of union and except can be used to generate difference:

```
df1.except(df2).union(df2.except(df1))
```

But this seems a bit awkward. In my experience, if something seems awkward, there's a better way to do it, especially in Scala.

Comment: I believe the phrase you're looking for is "symmetric difference."

Comment: Related to [Comparing two data frames in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54077336/10465355)

Comment: Someone has edit the orignal question from *Spark* to *SparkSQL*. The original questions was not in *SparkSQL*

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can always rewrite it as:

```
df1.unionAll(df2).except(df1.intersect(df2))
```

Seriously though this `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` / `MINUS` is pretty much a standard set of SQL combining operators. I am not aware of any system which provides XOR like operation out of the box. Most likely because it is trivial to implement using other three and there is not much to optimize there.

Comment: Thanks. If it was there, it'd probably do something like this under the covers anyway.

Answer (score 6):

why not the below?

```
df1.except(df2)
```

Comment: Because that doesn't perform an XOR.
I was looking for all elements NOT in the intersection.
Your code returns just the elements in d1 which are not in the intersection.
I also need the ones in d2 which are not in the intersection.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for Pyspark solution, you should use subtract() [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract).

Also, unionAll is deprecated in 2.0, use union() instead.

`df1.union(df2).subtract(df1.intersect(df2))`

Comment: Any reason this was downvoted?  pyspark doesn't have `except()`, but has `subtract()` which seems to have similar functionality as that provided in the approved solution.

Comment: didn't realized that -1 was given. yeah I am also interested in getting to know the reason why its got downvoted

Comment: Because it's about Scala, not Python.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the EXCEPT (or MINUS which is just an alias for EXCEPT) de-dups results. So if you expect "except" set (the diff you mentioned) + "intersect" set to be equal to original dataframe, consider this feature request that keeps duplicates:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21274

As I wrote there, "EXCEPT ALL" can be rewritten in Spark SQL as

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM    tab1 t1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tab2 t2
     ON (
        (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c) = (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c)
     )
WHERE
    COALESCE(t2.a, t2.b, t2.c) IS NULL
```

Comment: 1) Duplicates were not preferred. DFs here can be considered Sets for the sake of this question.
2)The original question was for Spark, not SparkSQL. I prefer coding in a functional style.

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be more efficient using a left join and then filtering out the nulls.

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("some_join_key", "some_other_join_key"),"left")
.where(col("column_just_present_in_df2").isNull)
```