# How to Persist an array in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm comparing two tables to find out difference between them (i.e Source and destination), for that I'm loading those tables to memory and the comparison happens as expected in the machine of configuration 8GB memory and 4 cores but when comparing large amount of data the system hangs and runs out of memory, so I used `persist()` of storagelevel `DISK_ONLY`

the machine is capable of holding 100,000 rows in memory to store that to `DISK` at a time and do the rest comparison operations, I'm trying like below:

```
var partition = math.ceil(c / 100000.toFloat).toInt
println(partition + " partition")
var a = 1
var data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(""))
var offset = 0
for (s <- a to partition) {

  val query = "(select * from destination LIMIT 100000 OFFSET " + offset + ") as src"
  data = data.union(spark.read.jdbc(url, query, connectionProperties).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
  offset += 100000
}
val dest = data.collect.toArray
val s = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dest, 1).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

yes off-course I can use partition but the problem is I need to supply `Lowerbounds`,`Upperbounds`,`NumPartitions` dynamically for fetching `100,000`   I tried like:

```
val destination = spark.read.options(options).jdbc(options("url"), options("dbtable"), "EMPLOYEE_ID", 1, 22, 21, new java.util.Properties()).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
```

it takes too much of time and storing those files into partitions though comparing operation is Iterative in nature its reading all the partitions for each and every step.

Coming to the problem

```
val dest = data.collect.toArray
val s = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dest, 1).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

the above lines convert all the partitioned  RDD's to Array and parallelizing it to single partition so I don't want to iterate through all the partitions again and again. But `val dest = data.collect.toArray` can't able to convert some huge amount of lines because of shortage in memory and seems it won't allow to `Persist()` an array in spark.

Is there is any way I can store and parallelize to one partition in `DISK`
Sorry for being a noob.

Thanks you..!

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Persist array in Spark ? Spark deals with RDD, Dataframe, Datasets. They have the capabilities to be persisted. You are calling persist within a loop, why you need this ?

Comment: @dumitru, I can't able to fetch the whole table in memory so I'm partitioning it and saving it to `DISK` for comparison form disk

Comment: when calling data.collect.toArray (collect it's a Spark action) it will bring you all the rows into memory

Comment: yes but only then I can convert it into a single file in DISK `val dest = data.collect.toArray
val s = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dest, 1).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)` Is there is any other way please advice.

Comment: I would let Spark do it's job. You said that you want the difference between two tables. So val src = spark.read.jdbc(url, "select * from source", connectionProperties), val dest = spark.read.jdbc(url, "select * from destination", connectionProperties) val diff = src.except(dest)

Comment: thank you, but I need to find mis-matches too, using primary key. cell comparison and I'm doing good with logics part now all I need is to convert all the partitions to one file.

Comment: If you were _good with logics_ , you wouldn't be having trouble with memory. I think you need to re-think this approach. Because you are trying to persist once you have collected all the data which is same as reading all the data at once. Also, way too many `var`s when most of them aren't even needed.

Comment: @philantrovert, Is there any way to convert all the RDD's to single RDD without using `collect()` method

Comment: I'd suggest what @dumitru suggested, `src.except(dest)` once you have the intersection, you can use the primary keys that are present in this new Dataframe to get data from both the dataframes which might be faster than what you're trying to do. Also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199901/how-to-obtain-the-difference-between-two-dataframes

Comment: @philantrovert ,I'm facing problem in fetching  huge amount of `source` and `destination` not in comparison.

Comment: Just to be clear - you are definitely on the wrong track here. I would like to help you, but it is unclear to me what exactly you are trying to do. Is it because you want the result written to a single file instead of _N_ files (where _N_ = partitions)?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt yes, while I'm reading the file from DISK its iterating for several times so I just want it as single file for comparison

Comment: Okay, so when you have your `DataFrame` with the result, simply call `coalesce(1)` and it will gather everything into a single partition. Note, that if you are truly dealing with big data, this will result in a OOM exception.

Comment: is there is any way doing it? the source or destination may exceed to TB's hence we dont have that infrastructure to hold both source and destination in memory that why going for `DISK` storage

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt, it worked thank you so much..!