# Pyspark - distinct records based on 2 columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-rds, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have 2 dataframes, say `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` data comes from a database, and `df2` is the new data I receive from my client.  I need to process the new data, and perform `UPSERTs` based on whether it is a new record or an existing record to be updated.

Sample data output:

```
df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("xxx1","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("xxx2","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("xxx3","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("xxx4","81A01","TERR NAME 01","CA"),("xx5","81A01","TERR NAME 01","ME")], ["zip_code","territory_code","territory_name","state"])
df2= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("xxx1","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("xxx2","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("x103","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ")], ["zip_code","territory_code","territory_name","state"])

df1.show()
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|zip_code|territory_code|territory_name|state|
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|    xxx1|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
|    xxx2|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
|    xxx3|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
|    xxx4|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   CA|
|    xxx5|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   ME|
+---------------------------------------------

# Print out information about this data
df2.show()
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|zip_code|territory_code|territory_name|state|
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|    xxx1|         81A01|  TERR NAME 55|   NY|
|    xxx2|         81A01|  TERR NAME 55|   NY|
|    x103|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
+---------------------------------------------
```

Expected results:
I need to compare **df2** dataframe with **df1**.
Create 2 new datasets based on above compare, i.e., records to be updated & records to be appended / inserted  to database.

if **zip_code** & **territory_code** are same, then it is an UPDATE, else it is an INSERT to database.

For example:
New dataframe output for INSERT:

```
 +--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
 |zip_code|territory_code|territory_name|state|
 +--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
 |    x103|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
 +---------------------------------------------
```

New dataframe for UPDATE:

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|zip_code|territory_code|territory_name|state|
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|    xxx1|         81A01|  TERR NAME 55|   NY|
|    xxx2|         81A01|  TERR NAME 55|   NY|
+---------------------------------------------
```

Can someone please help me? And I am using AWS Glue.

UPDATE: SOLUTION (Using join & subtract)

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, (df1.zip_code == df2.zip_code_new) & (df1.territory_code == df2.territory_code_new))
df5=df3.drop("zip_code", "territory_code", "territory_name", "state")
df5.show()

+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|zip_code_new|territory_code_new|territory_name_new|state_new|
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|        x103|             81A01|      TERR NAME 01|       NJ|
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+

df4=df2.subtract(df5)
df4.show()

+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|zip_code_new|territory_code_new|territory_name_new|state_new|
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|    xxx1    |         81A01    |  TERR NAME 55    |   NY    |
|    xxx2    |         81A01    |  TERR NAME 55    |   NY    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For RDS database updation, I use pymysql/Mysqldb:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com", "username", "password", "databasename")
cursor = db.cursor()

#cursor.execute("REPLACE INTO table SELECT * FROM table_stg")
insertQry = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('xxx1','81A01','TERR NAME 55','NY') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE territory_name='TERR NAME 55', state='NY'"
n=cursor.execute(insertQry)
db.commit()
cursor.fetchall()
db.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: Please write your question in a better way next time. It was (maybe still is) hard to understand.
Maybe you should also provide a dataset (I mean 4-5 sample data) so that other people can test your code.

Comment: I think, I have given enough information, and clarity in my question, not sure what made it negative voting.  Anyway, I will edit the question and make it shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution sketch:

1. project both frames on your unique key (zip_code and territory)
2. Use the spark dataframe api to compute the intersection and difference between both dataframes. See this link: [How to obtain the difference between two DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199901/how-to-obtain-the-difference-between-two-dataframes)
3. do an update for the intersection of the keys
4. do an insert for the difference (within new dataframe, not within existing data)

In scala this would look something like this -- and it should be quite similar in python:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class ZipTerr(zip_code: String, territory_code: String, 
    territory_name: String, state:String)

case class Key(zip_code: String, territory_code: String)

val spark: SparkSession

val newData = spark.createDataFrame(List(
  ZipTerr("xxx1", "81A01", "TERR NAME 01", "NJ"),
  ZipTerr("xxx2", "81A01", "TERR NAME 01", "NJ"),
  ZipTerr("xxx3", "81A01", "TERR NAME 01", "NJ"),
  ZipTerr("xxx4", "81A01", "TERR NAME 01", "CA"),
  ZipTerr("xx5","81A01","TERR NAME 01","ME")
))

val oldData = spark.createDataFrame(List(
  ZipTerr("xxx1","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),
  ZipTerr("xxx2","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),
  ZipTerr("x103","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ")
))

val newKeys = newData.map(z => Key(z.getAs("zip_code"), z.getAs("territory_code")))
val oldKeys = oldData.map(z => Key(z.getAs("zip_code"), z.getAs("territory_code")))

val keysToInsert = newKeys.except(oldKeys)
val keysToUpdate = newKeys.intersect(oldKeys)
```

Does this help?

Note: the name of your variables suggests that you are working with glue dynamic frames. Yet you are assigning plain spark dataframes to them using the `sqlContext.createDataFrame` function.

Comment: Thank you @user152468, will try this and keep you posted.  Is there a way to pull entire record from newData / oldData based on keys from the keysToInsert / keyToUpdate by way of join & drop unwanted columns?  Apologies if its basics, but am still learning pyspark.

Comment: Hi user152468, I was able to get the desired results, based on your suggestions, plus also other reference.  I have updated the code & the results in my question. Just a note, think except is replaced by subtract, and there is no intersect in pyspark as far as I googled. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @YuvaKumar. Glad you made it. Pyspark seems to be quite different in the language constructs from plain spark.

Answer (score 1):

For the clarity, am reproducing the solution here with code snippets:

```
df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("xxx1","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("xxx2","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("xxx3","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("xxx4","81A01","TERR NAME 01","CA"),("xx5","81A01","TERR NAME 01","ME")], ["zip_code","territory_code","territory_name","state"])
df2= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("xxx1","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("xxx2","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("x103","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ")], ["zip_code_new","territory_code_new","territory_name_new","state"])

df1.show()
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|zip_code|territory_code|territory_name|state|
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|    xxx1|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
|    xxx2|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
|    xxx3|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
|    xxx4|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   CA|
|    xxx5|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   ME|
+---------------------------------------------

# Print out information about this data
df2.show()
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|zip_code_new|territory_code_new|territory_name_new|state_new|
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|    xxx1    |         81A01    |  TERR NAME 55    |   NY    |
|    xxx2    |         81A01    |  TERR NAME 55    |   NY    |
|    x103    |         81A01    |  TERR NAME 01    |   NJ    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Get the new records, which can be inserted to mysql using an "**append**" operation

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, (df1.zip_code == df2.zip_code_new) & (df1.territory_code == df2.territory_code_new))
df5=df3.drop("zip_code", "territory_code", "territory_name", "state")
df5.show()

+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|zip_code_new|territory_code_new|territory_name_new|state_new|
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|        x103|             81A01|      TERR NAME 01|       NJ|
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
```

Then get the remaining records that need to be updated to the mysql database. We can use, `arr = df1.collect()`, followed by `for r in arr:`, in case of pure python needs, otherwise, we can use pandas iterators processing each records.

```
df4=df2.subtract(df5)
df4.show()

+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|zip_code_new|territory_code_new|territory_name_new|state_new|
+------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|    xxx1    |         81A01    |  TERR NAME 55    |   NY    |
|    xxx2    |         81A01    |  TERR NAME 55    |   NY    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hope this helps someone in need.  Do let me know if there are better ways for dataframe iteration in the above scenario. Thanks