# Comparing two data frames in Spark (performance)

Tags: java, scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to compare two dataframes in my spark application. I went through the following post.
[How to obtain the difference between two DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199901/how-to-obtain-the-difference-between-two-dataframes)

However, I don't understand why the approach in the best answer

```
df1.unionAll(df2).except(df1.intersect(df2))
```

is better than the one in the question

```
df1.except(df2).union(df2.except(df1))
```

Can anyone explain?
As per my understanding, the latter works with two smaller datasets and former works with a large dataset. Is it because the latter does a distinct as a part of union? Even then, if it is more likely case that two data frames have same records, we are dealing with a small dataset in the latter case.

Comment: As the asker of the initial question, Here's some clarification: Neither is "better", the question wasn't about correctness, efficiency or performance, it was about the most appropriate idiomatic approach. The "correct" answer was chosen (by me) because it addressed that fact that an exact operation didn't exist, and that a combination of other logical operations was required. As is shown in the answers submitted below, which is "best" in terms of efficiency, etc. will always depend on context.

Comment: @Ajay Vepakomma, I'm using the code but `except` is not accepted, throws an `invalid` syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider a scenario where both `df1` and `df2` (of size N and M respectively) are too large to be broadcasted, but there is no overlap between `df1` and `df2`.

Let's call it the result `di`.  In such case `df1.intersect(df2)` will require a full shuffle of N + M rows, however the size of the output will be equal to 0. In such case `df1.unionAll(df2).except(di)` can be executed as a broadcast join (such optimization might require [adaptive execution](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9850) unless specific plan is forced by the user). It is also important to note that such plan doesn't require caching.

In contrast the cost of `df1.except(df2).union(df2.except(df1))`  will be constant in regards to the cardinality of the intersection.

At the same time, if `d1` is to large to be broadcasted, it already has a partitioning compatible with `except`, so the remaining query shouldn't require additional shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

First things first - `unionAll` is deprecated as of version 2 of Spark. Please use `union` instead, as you did in the second snippet.

Second, in the answers to the question, you're referencing to, there is no information, that the first piece of code is better. I have prepared such a scenario. For me, the first one took 31s and the second 18s. In my case `df1` has ~3 million rows and `df2` ~ 1 million, 5 columns each.

If we now analyse the optimized logical execution plan for the first query:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 21
+- LocalLimit 21
   +- Aggregate [_c0#10, _c1#11, _c2#12, _c3#13, _c4#14], [cast(_c0#10 as string) AS _c0#67, cast(_c1#11 as string) AS _c1#68, cast(_c2#12 as string) AS _c2#69, cast(_c3#13 as string) AS _c3#70, cast(_c4#14 as string) AS _c4#71]
      +- Join LeftAnti, (((((_c0#10 <=> _c0#52) && (_c1#11 <=> _c1#53)) && (_c2#12 <=> _c2#54)) && (_c3#13 <=> _c3#55)) && (_c4#14 <=> _c4#56))
         :- Union
         :  :- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11,_c2#12,_c3#13,_c4#14] csv
         :  +- Project [_c0#30, _c1#31, _c2#32, _c3#33, cast(_c4#34 as double) AS _c4#40]
         :     +- Relation[_c0#30,_c1#31,_c2#32,_c3#33,_c4#34] csv
         +- Aggregate [_c0#52, _c1#53, _c2#54, _c3#55, _c4#56], [_c0#52, _c1#53, _c2#54, _c3#55, _c4#56]
            +- Join LeftSemi, (((((_c0#52 <=> _c0#30) && (_c1#53 <=> _c1#31)) && (_c2#54 <=> _c2#32)) && (_c3#55 <=> _c3#33)) && (_c4#56 <=> _c4#46))
               :- Relation[_c0#52,_c1#53,_c2#54,_c3#55,_c4#56] csv
               +- Project [_c0#30, _c1#31, _c2#32, _c3#33, cast(_c4#34 as double) AS _c4#46]
                  +- Relation[_c0#30,_c1#31,_c2#32,_c3#33,_c4#34] csv
```

We can see, that there is `Union` and `Join`(intersection) running concurrently, which is very costly, especially `Union`, whereas for the second query:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 21
+- LocalLimit 21
   +- Union
      :- LocalLimit 21
      :  +- Aggregate [_c0#10, _c1#11, _c2#12, _c3#13, _c4#14], [cast(_c0#10 as string) AS _c0#120, cast(_c1#11 as string) AS _c1#121, cast(_c2#12 as string) AS _c2#122, cast(_c3#13 as string) AS _c3#123, cast(_c4#14 as string) AS _c4#124]
      :     +- Join LeftAnti, (((((_c0#10 <=> _c0#30) && (_c1#11 <=> _c1#31)) && (_c2#12 <=> _c2#32)) && (_c3#13 <=> _c3#33)) && (_c4#14 <=> _c4#98))
      :        :- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11,_c2#12,_c3#13,_c4#14] csv
      :        +- Project [_c0#30, _c1#31, _c2#32, _c3#33, cast(_c4#34 as double) AS _c4#98]
      :           +- Relation[_c0#30,_c1#31,_c2#32,_c3#33,_c4#34] csv
      +- LocalLimit 21
         +- Aggregate [_c0#30, _c1#31, _c2#32, _c3#33, _c4#104], [cast(_c0#30 as string) AS _c0#130, cast(_c1#31 as string) AS _c1#131, cast(_c2#32 as string) AS _c2#132, cast(_c3#33 as string) AS _c3#133, cast(_c4#104 as string) AS _c4#134]
            +- Join LeftAnti, (((((_c0#30 <=> _c0#10) && (_c1#31 <=> _c1#11)) && (_c2#32 <=> _c2#12)) && (_c3#33 <=> _c3#13)) && (_c4#104 <=> _c4#14))
               :- Project [_c0#30, _c1#31, _c2#32, _c3#33, cast(_c4#34 as double) AS _c4#104]
               :  +- Relation[_c0#30,_c1#31,_c2#32,_c3#33,_c4#34] csv
               +- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11,_c2#12,_c3#13,_c4#14] csv
```

There are two `LeftAnti` running concurrently (relative compliments). This takes less space and is more efficient. This can be seen in SparkUI:

First query:
[image: First query]
Second query:
[image: Second query]

In the first case, stage 7 - `Union` is the most costly, whereas in the second case stages 42 and 41 (above) are relatively faster.