# Comparing two large dataframes w/ pySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199901/how-to-obtain-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-dataframes) mentions symmetric difference and leveraging code `df1.except(df2).union(df2.except(df1))` and/or`df1.unionAll(df2).except(df1.intersect(df2))` but I'm getting syntax errors when using `except`.

I'm trying to compare two dataframes who can have up to 50 or 50+ columns. I have the working code below but need to avoid hard coding columns.

**sample code and example**

```
# Create the two dataframes
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',1000,'ind','IT','2/11/2019'),(22,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                 (33,'Kom',3500,'uk','IT','2/11/2019'),(44,'Nom',4000,'can','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                 (55,'Vom',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019'),(66,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019')],
                                 ['No','Name','Sal','Address','Dept','Join_Date']) 
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',1000,'ind','IT','2/11/2019'),(22,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                  (33,'Kom',3000,'uk','IT','2/11/2019'),(44,'Nom',4000,'can','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                  (55,'Xom',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019'),(77,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019')],
                                  ['No','Name','Sal','Address','Dept','Join_Date']) 
df1 = df1.withColumn('FLAG',lit('DF1'))
df2 = df2.withColumn('FLAG',lit('DF2'))

# Concatenate the two DataFrames, to create one big dataframe.
df = df1.union(df2)


#Use window function to check if the count of same rows is more than 1 and if it indeed is, then mark column FLAG as SAME, else keep it the way it is. Finally, drop the duplicates.

my_window = Window.partitionBy('No','Name','Sal','Address','Dept','Join_Date').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)
df = df.withColumn('FLAG', when((count('*').over(my_window) > 1),'SAME').otherwise(col('FLAG'))).dropDuplicates()
df.show()
```

Comment: Do you have to code it yourself or can you use a tool for it?

Comment: @Saša Zejnilović, i can use packages and helper libs. I haven’t found any in pySpark yet

Comment: https://github.com/AbsaOSS/hermes has a DatasetComparison module. A stand-alone spark-job. In scala, it can be used as a library as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all column names from `df` and use that list as parameter for the `Window` function:

```python
cols = df.columns
cols.remove('FLAG')
my_window = Window.partitionBy(cols).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)
```

The remaining code stays unchanged.

Comment: why use ```cols.remove('FLAG')``` ?

Comment: `FLAG` is the column that contains the information whether a row was orgininally coming from df1 or df2. You don't want this column to be part of the window definition.

Comment: I'm using the same code, but getting different output, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272046/customize-large-datasets-comparison-in-pyspark @werner