# Customize large datasets comparison in pySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, duplicates

I'm using the code below to compare two dataframe and identified differences. However, I'm noticing that I'm simply overwriting my values ( `combine_df`). My goal  is to Flag if row values are different. But not sure what I"m doing wrong.

```
#Find the overlapping columns in order to compare their values
cols = set(module_df.columns) & (set(expected_df.columns))
```

```
#create filter dataframes only with the overlapping columns
filter_module = expected_df.select(list(cols))
filter_expected = expected_df.select(list(cols))
```

```
#create Flag columns to serve as identifier 
filter_module = filter_module.withColumn('FLAG',lit('module'))
filter_expected = filter_expected.withColumn('FLAG',lit('expected'))

#join dataframes
combine_df = filter_module.union(filter_expected)

#get column names in order to iterate/partition through 
combine_cols = combine_df.columns
combine_cols.remove('FLAG')
```

```
#leverage Windows function 
my_window = Window.partitionBy(combine_cols).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)

#dataframe with validation flag
combine_df = combine_df.withColumn('FLAG', when((count('*').over(my_window) > 1),'SAME').otherwise(col('FLAG'))).dropDuplicates()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used correct df

```
#instead of this
filter_module = expected_df.select(list(cols))
filter_expected = expected_df.select(list(cols))
#use this
filter_module = module_df.select(list(cols))
filter_expected = expected_df.select(list(cols))
```

Comment: you're right. Made a silly time costing mistake. This is the other question we were discussing , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270258/pyspark-checking-for-unique-rows-after-joining-on-multiple-columns?noredirect=1#comment110132606_62270258