# Read only Delta between 2 versions of deltaLake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse, delta-lake

Is there a way to read only the delta between 2 versions of deltaLake? specifically in Synapse

I have tried

```
%%pyspark
import delta
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, asc

df_delta = spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", 0) \
  .option("endingVersion", 1) \
  .load("/pathtoDeltaLake")


display(df_delta)
```

But the above seems to read more than just the delta between 2 versions. (only 1 row was added in version 1)

Answer (score 2):

Right now, the [Delta Change Feed](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) is available only on Databricks (and only starting with specific runtime version), so you can't use it on Synapse. The options `readChangeFeed`, `startingVersion` & `endingVersion` are simply ignored by the open source Delta library that you're using on Synapse.

So you either execute this code on the Databricks and write as a separate table that could be read from Synapse, or you read each version into a separate dataframes (using `.option("versionAsOf", version)`) and the use some code to find diff (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199901/how-to-obtain-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-dataframes)).

Comment: Is this change available in Open source delta library now?

Comment: not yet, later this year - see roadmap issue on github